# TypeError: (0 , _firestore.default)(...).collection(...).doc(...).add is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, native

I'm trying to save datas in `Firebase` but i get erro on console:

> TypeError: (0 , _firestore.default)(...).collection(...).doc(...).add is not a function

When I use this code below without `.doc()`, its works.

```
createUser: async (user) => {

        try{
           await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email,user.password)
            const uid = Firebase.getCurrentUser().uid;           

            const teste = firestore().collection('users').add({
                name: user.name,
                email: user.email
            })

            delete user.password
            
            return{...user, uid}

        }catch(erro){
            console.log('Show:', erro)
        }
        
    }
```

But  when i use `.doc ()` I always get that error. It looks like doc is not working

```
createUser: async (user) => {

        try{
           await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email,user.password)
            const uid = Firebase.getCurrentUser().uid;           

            const teste = firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).add({
                name: user.name,
                email: user.email
            })

            delete user.password
            
            return{...user, uid}

        }catch(erro){
            console.log('Show:', erro)
        }
        
    }
```

This function create an user in `Firebase authentication`  and get id `uid` of created user. I'd like to use this `uid` to create a new collection and the `doc()` being the same of `uid`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "add", use "set".

```
const teste = firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).set({
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email
        })
```

Since add is used for generating a random unique ID.

[Documentation where this is stated.](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage)